# Sharepoint 2010 List with Values 0,1,2 shown as Text

Tags: list, sharepoint, user-defined-functions

I've got a sharepoint list, in one column we have 0,1,2 I would like the list not to show 0,1,2 but if there is an 0 I would like the text 'to be checked' shown if there is a 1 'yes' and 2 'no'.

Is there any possibility with SPD and without VS?

With regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating a [calculated column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071%28v=office.14%29.aspx) with value based on conditional formula (similar to Excel). It is easily manageable from SharePoint web interface. Then you could show this column in your view instead of the original one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Conditional Formatting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/balsharfi/archive/2011/10/20/sharepoint-lists-conditional-formatting-using-sharepoint-designer-2010.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I just tried to use it, but I only found options to change the appearance of the list not to replace the integer with a text, did you worked with it and could give me further hints?